# Media Player how to recover when create fails?

Tags: java, android, media-player, freeze, creation

I have an app that plays randomly every second 1 of 20 different sounds . After almost 1000 successful times the media player create function starts to return always null. The problem remains even when I leave the app and I start it again. The only solution is when I install the app again or I switch off and on the device.

Is there any method to recover from this state? If I do release or reset, media player was already null and they produce an exception.

The sequence I do every second is the following:

```
if (mp != null)
{   
    if (mp.isPlaying()) 
    {
       mp.stop();   
    }   
    if (mp != null) mp.release();   
    if (mp != null) mp = null;  
}   

mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

if (mp !=null)
{
   mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
   {           
      public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
      {
    if (mp != null) mp.start();
      }
   };
 }
 else
 {
    // error, what should I do here to recover from this situation?
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found the solution. I have now played more than 10000 audios without reproducing the error anymore.

I want to thank to kcoppock for his help, I do not create and release now because it is much better to change the data source as he explained, but it was not the main problem.

**The final solution was to convert all the mp3 files into ogg files !!!!**

Media Player has definitely problems with mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that even when you're releasing the `MediaPlayer`, the OS may not have let go of the resources yet by the time you try to use it again, especially 20 times per second. I would actually recommend that you look into using a `SoundPool` instead for something like this.

Regardless, to do this with a `MediaPlayer`, you should keep only **one** reference, and reuse that object each time for a different sound. Since you're using raw resources for playback, a typically reuse scenario would be something like this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.sound);

//Resets the MediaPlayer state but keeps the resources
mp.reset();

//Sets the data source to the requested sound (R.raw.sound)
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());

//Prepare the MediaPlayer to play and then start
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it right now. I have 20 audios, but I play just one sound per second. According to what you say, I would use mp.release() just when we destroy the app, right?

Comment: Yup! I would make `mp` a class variable, initialize it in `onCreate()` or `onResume()` (`mp = new MediaPlayer()`), and release it in `onDestroy()` or `onPause()` respectively.

Comment: Now it is much better and it played until almost 4000 audios without error, but at the end the error came again. The question is, once the error comes, how can we recover from this state? Media player does not play anymore even if I leave the app. :-( Anyway I´m very thankful with your answer, lets see if we somehow avoid the error or we recover it.

Comment: I will try this a little bit better: In order to reuse a MediaPlayer object that is in the Error state and recover from the error, reset() can be called to restore the object to its Idle state.

Comment: The error is in Prepare: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC. It remains when I start the app again. From your code I had to modify to: mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); because yours where playing different things... maybe the offset is producing the error...

Comment: Ok, now I have tested it with PrepareAsync and the error is in SetDataSource: java.io.IOException: SetDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x8000000. If I try to play a mp3 song with media player, out of my app, it says that media player does not support this format of audio. Without the error this song was always played without any kind of problem.